# LIBGDX HTML runtime error but works on android and desktop

Tags: android, gwt, libgdx

I'm having an issue where my game compiles to android and desktop but is getting a runtime error saying it can't find any of the files in the package `walljumper.tools`. It gets all the way to the loading screen, loads and then says this in the browser

```
GwtApplication: exception: walljumper/tools/Assets
walljumper/tools/Assets
```

and says this in the console

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: walljumper/tools/Assets
at com.me.walljumper.WallJumper.create(WallJumper.java:23)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.GwtApplication.setupLoop(GwtApplication.java:177)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.GwtApplication$1$1.update(GwtApplication.java:138)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.preloader.Preloader$1$1.onSuccess(Preloader.java:184)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.preloader.AssetDownloader$4$1.onEvent(AssetDownloader.java:171)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: walljumper.tools.Assets
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1090)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1196)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 15 more
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set the asset importer up?  See http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2372

Comment: Fixed this, eventually just put all the packages in the walljumper package.

Answer (score 0):

In your Something.gwt.xml in your shared project do you correctly list the translatable source packages?

```
<module>
    <source path="walljumper/" />
</module>
```